# Treafik Path Routing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I want to reach a docker-compose service under api.example.com/example. Therefore I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
  example:
    image: example    
    labels:
            - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.example.com;PathPrefixStrip:/example/"
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.protocol=http"
            - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https"
```

I can reach the service under this path. But all the links in the page route to a wrong url like `api.example.com/link` instead of `api.example.com/example/link`

Also the css is not loading correctly because of this path issue.
What would be the right path configuration to get this working?

Reading from the docs, X-Forwarded-Prefix should be the solution, but there is no doc about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to route requests matching `api.example.com/example/*` to this `example` service. Then you should use `PathPrefix:/example/`.

What you have is expected: `PathPrefixStrip`, as the name suggests, try to match the path, then, remove it before routing traffic to the service.

Comment: yes but my service behind is listening on `/` not on `/example/` so I have to strip the `example`, so this will not work, no?

Comment: As far as I know, servers don't listen to a path, they always "listen" to `/` (they are on a host). Your apis, though, can be on any path you like, leaving `/` to a 404 page.

Comment: yeah this is right, but I therefore use traefik. I want to have several servers listening on `/` but path routed by traefik. I thought PathPrefixStrip is exactly therefore. Instead, I would not understand the use of traefik with paths

Comment: The goal here is to have a finer grade scaling control, decoupling the system (concept of microservice) while appear to the outside world as one server.

Comment: When you say you want to have several servers listening on /, do you mean that a server A and a server both respond to domain/test ?

Comment: no one to domain/test1 and the other to domain/test2,

Comment: Ok... then what's your problem with it changing to `api.example.com/link`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add rules ?

```
- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.example.com;PathPrefixStrip:/example/; AddPrefix: /example"
```